# Camera to nfc - best photoquality

Tags: java, android, bitmap, nfc

For my application, I need to save a photo, taken from camera of a device, on an 7.7k nfc chip.
In the onActivityResult, I resize the bitmap as here :

```
String fileName = "original";
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName + ".jpg";

//Resizing
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
Bitmap current = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
Bitmap resized = resizeBitMapImage(path,largeur,(int)(largeur*1.8));
```

with

```
    public static Bitmap resizeBitMapImage(String filePath, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {
    Bitmap bitMapImage = null;
    try {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        double sampleSize = 0;
        Boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - targetHeight) >= Math.abs(options.outWidth
                - targetWidth);
        if (options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 1638) {
            sampleSize = scaleByHeight ? options.outHeight / targetHeight : options.outWidth / targetWidth;
            sampleSize = (int) Math.pow(2d, Math.floor(Math.log(sampleSize) / Math.log(2d)));
        }
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[128];
        while (true) {
            try {
                options.inSampleSize = (int) sampleSize;
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"inSampleSize" + options.inSampleSize);
                bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
                break;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    sampleSize = sampleSize + 1 ;
                } catch (Exception ex1) {

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return bitMapImage;
}
```

(Found on SO)

And then, I save it on the chip with :

```
    NdefRecord picRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA,  "image/jpeg".getBytes(), null, byteArray);
```

When I choose a width of 200, and a compression of 50, the picture takes about 7k, but the quality is quite low. The bitmap is a contact photo.

So my questions :

- What should I use as width, height, compression,  in order to get the best photo quality (less than 7k?
- Should the camera be set on high or low resolution ?
- PNG or JPEG compression ?

Comment: You can't fit much of a photo in 7K.

Comment: Just for info, I get the best quality, with a fixed inSampleSize of 16, high resolution on my camera, and I played with the compression : between 60 and 70. The photo is quite good according to the small size.
And no use of resizeBitMapImage().
Tks for reply.